# Changing multiple different classes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been building a standalone web app for myself to learn about asp.net MVC4 and in so doing have been learning more about HTML 5, CSS and JavaScript.  Needless to say I have learned alot and realized their is much more to learn. Before I ask any questions however I do a thorough search of this site and others to try and find things myself as I find I learn better by doing.

My issue here is just trying to find a way to simplify my JavaScript code if at all possible. I am not looking for JQuery at this time but will be looking into it in the future. For now strictly JavaScript.

Here is a portion of my JavaScript code that I am looking to truncate.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', tap);

    function tap() {
        var elements = document.getElementByClassName('tap');
            for ( var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                elements[i].innerHTML = '<img src="/Content/Images/tap_icon.jpg>")';
            }
        }
```

This code works great for what I intended it to do which is change the element class  of 'tap' to a specific image no matter how many elements have the class name.

The problem is I have 8 different classes that I am doing this with one for each image that needs to be displayed. Shown below are 2 of the functions.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', tap);

    function tap() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tap');
            for ( var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                elements[i].innerHTML = '<img src="/Content/Images/tap_icon.jpg">';
            }
        }

    window.addEventListener('load', redMana);

    function redMana() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
            for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
            {
                elements[i].innerHTML = '<img src="/Content/Images/Red_Mana.jpg">';
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to bundle this all into one function or would it be better to keep them separate to maintain readability and easier updating if new file names are created for images/new classes added to the app.

Anything that would point me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you all for you knowledge and assistance.

Edit:

Sorry I am coming back to this so late. I am in the midst of moving and starting a new job.

I have updated my JavaScript File to reflect the answer provided however when I run the application, only the first call fires.

Here is the full script for right now I will need to add further calls.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', setImage);

    function setImage(className, imageName) {
        var elements = document.getElementByClassName(className);

        for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = '<img src="/Content/Images/' + imageName + '.jpg">';
    }

    setImage('tap', 'tap_icon');
    setImage('c2', '2cmana');
    setImage('red', 'Red_Mana');
}
```

When I run the app the first call

```
    setImage('tap', 'tap_icon');
```

fires, but then the following calls do nothing. I don't know what I am missing on this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to not repeat the same code over and over you could add parameters to the function assuming it's the same function with different input:

```
 //For Example:
 function setImage(className, imageName) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        elements[i].innerHTML = '<img src="/Content/Images/' + imageName + '.jpg">';
    }
 }
```

You could then call the function like this:

```
setImage('red', 'Red_Mana');
setImage('tap', 'tap_icon');
```

Comment: All 8 functions are the identical except for the class names and image files. I believe that for the time being this is going to be the best option for me with my current skill set. Now the only question I have is when you say call the function is that still in the .js file under the closing brackets for the function or is that entered into the html code in the view?

Comment: Just in the same .js file

Comment: OK thank you.  And the eventListener should remain the same as well correct? Otherwise it wouldn't run on page load.

Comment: again thank you this makes things much cleaner and as far as I can see easier to maintain as well once I am more information. As always your knowledge and willingness to assist is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi I have updated my code per your recommendations however it is not working as expected. I have updated the question with more information for your review.

Comment: Can you see the correct html being generated when you look at the page with the inspector in chrome? or do you see any console errors?

Comment: The correct html is generated with the exception of an id and not a class which i have corrected. There is a console error which is listed as "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at setImage

Comment: Sorry i double checked on this and the correct html is generated for the first call however each call after that is not generating the <img> tag. The above error still shows.

Comment: It varies. Some pages will have 2 or 3 some may have at most 15 but that would be rare. On average I would put it around 8-10.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you're looking to the future I'm proving an answer with ES6 features.

To simplify things you could abstract all similar codes and build a configuration-base code like so:

```
const baseImgPath = "/Content/Images/",
      classImageMap = [
        { className: 'tap', imageName: 'tap_icon.jpg' },
        { className: 'red', imageName: 'Red_Mana.jpg' }
      ];

window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoad);

function onWindowLoad() {
  classImageMap.forEach(setImageToClass);
}

function setImageToClass(mapping) {
  let { className, imageName } = mapping;
  document
   .getElementsByClassName(className)
   .forEach(elem => elem.innerHTML = `<img src="${baseImgPath+imageName}"/>` );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding a future option. I really appriciate all the help that everyone here has provided. I will keep this handy and look into it as I progress with my knowledge and understanding of JavaScript and in the future JQuery.